# Let $M$ be the set of all $2\times2$ real matrices, and define $f:M\rightarrow M$ by $f(A)=A^3$. Is $f$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that in a finite field, injectivity implies surjectivity, but we are working in a ring, not a field. Also $f$ is not injective. I'm sure an argument could be made using a system of equations of an arbitrary cube, but there must be a more elegant solution. Something using Cayley-Hamilton, maybe? Any advice on how to approach this is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, $f$ is not surjective: let $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. If there were a matrix $A$ such that $A^3=B$ then we would have $A^6=B^2=0$, but then necessarily $A^2=0$ which contradicts $A^3=B\neq 0$.